# Trouble Opening Android App WebView or Loading in Image View to Shared Image

Tags: java, image, url, webview, imageview

Good morning everyone, I have this issue with Android Gradle Java that I haven't been able to solve. I have this URL "file://192.168.10.2/Pictures/logo.png" which points to a shared folder on a computer in a local network. I can access it normally from a PC browser, but the problem arises when I try to open it from an Android application using a WebView or a web browser. I have also tried using Picasso, but I haven't received a successful response. Can someone please help me?

This is my actual code:

Using Picasso
`Picasso.get().load("file://ip/Pictures/logo.png").into(imgImagen);`

Using Web View
`detalleTagWebView.loadUrl("file://192.168.10.2/Pictures/logo.png");`